# FileNotFoundException in aspnet core web docker compose environment

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm working to dockerize my aspnet core identity server web application. I have already tested running application from docker container and it works.

```
$ docker run -d ^
-e "KeyFilePath"="/app/certs/authFile.cer" ^
-p 5000:5000 ^
-v e:/certs:/app/certs/ ^
--name identity ^
identity:0.1-docker
```

Now, I'm wiring this in my docker-compose.yml where my application is unable to find the file specified at **/app/certs/**. Here is my docker-compose section of identity server

```
services:
  identity:
    image: identity.api:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Identity/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqlserver
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - "e:/certs:/app/certs"
    environment:
      - KeyFilePath="/app/certs/authFile.cer"
```

I've been troubleshooting this for quite sometime now. Volume is mapped smoothly when running using **docker run** with `-v` but unable to achieve the same from `docker-compose up identity`

With `docker exec -it <container-id> sh` , I can see the file existence in the required directory. Still, my app is unable to access the file.

In code, simply checking the existence using `File.Exists(keyFilePath)` which

- returns `true` when container is started via `docker run` command.
- returns `false` when started using `docker-compose up identity`. Log for the check says `File.Exists ["/app/certs/authFile.cer"] => False.` even when the file is present.

Any idea about the root cause for this weird issue?

I'm running

1. Aspnet Core 2.1 Web Application
2. Docker Desktop version: `Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61`
3. Docker Compose version: `docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192`

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try to change

from

```
environment:
  - KeyFilePath="/app/certs/authFile.cer"
```

to

```
environment:
  - KeyFilePath=/app/certs/authFile.cer
```

Comment: That's definitely where I messed up. I have checked with `docker-compose up` and the issue is fixed. Thanks a lot. 

Just one thing. How come the same works through `docker run` but fails from `docker-compose`?

Comment: It's basically ymal files syntax and console syntax. KeyFilePath="/app/certs/authFile.cer" equal -e "KeyFilePath"="\"/app/certs/authFile.cer\"" that why you get incorrect environment.